# Symfony2 Doctrine2 autoincrement field with custom id generator

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm facing a problem with a custom id generator, auto-incrementation and doctrine-migrations in Symfony (2.7) with Doctrine (2.5) and MySQL.

When I use the custom generator, the id field does not get the AUTO_INCREMENT status in the migrations:diff output.
When I add the autoincrement manually in the yaml then all referenced table-columns also get the AUTO_INCREMENT.

How can I use auto increment on my primary entity with a custom generator without affecting the references?

The entity (sites.orm.yml):

```
type: entity
table: sites
id:
  id:
    type: integer
    column: id
    generator:
      strategy: CUSTOM
    customIdGenerator:
      class: AssignableIdentityGenerator
```

The generator:

```
class AssignableIdentityGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator {
  public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity) {
    return $entity->getId() ? : (int) $em->getConnection()->lastInsertId();
  }

  public function isPostInsertGenerator() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Migrations:diff output keeps being this (removes the AUTO_INCREMENT):

```
ALTER TABLE sites CHANGE id id INT NOT NULL;
```

If I add

```
options:
  autoincrement: true
```

I don't get an ALTER for the sites table, which is correct because it keeps the AUTO_INCREMENT, but instead I get

```
ALTER TABLE other_table CHANGE site_id site_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
```

on a referencing table, which is not correct.

Doctrine natively suports the AUTO_INCREMENT with its own IdentityGenerator and I think I found the spot in Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool::gatherColumn where this takes effect, but it's deep in a private method:

```
if ($class->isIdGeneratorIdentity() && $class->getIdentifierFieldNames() == array($mapping['fieldName'])) {
    $options['autoincrement'] = true;
}
```

Unfortunately Doctrine is not very friendly to extensions (many private methods/properties or classes being instantiated instead of using injectable services).

Would anyone have a solution to this problem?
Or maybe even a whole different idea on how to get an id field that is both auto-incrementable and manually settable.

Answer (score 4):

> Would anyone have a solution to this problem? Or maybe even a whole different idea on how to get an id field that is both auto-incrementable and manually settable.

I got this solution for you:

**First:** You need to set up your ID strategy to "AUTO"

```
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 protected $id;
```

---

**Second:** If you want to set up your ID manually, you need to change the metadata (*before flush*) of your class. There you can change your **IdGeneratorType**

```
/**
 * @param EntityManager $em
 * @param mixed         $object
 */
protected function changeIdGeneratorType(EntityManager $em, $object)
{
     if ($object->getId() !== null) {
         $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($object));
         $metadata->setIdGeneratorType($metadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
     }
}
```

---

```
$metadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE
```

With this GeneratorType you will be able to set your ID's manually.

---

**Now you will be able to both auto-incrementable and manually settable ID's**

Comment: Thanks your your reply!
Could you clarify where this changeIdGeneratorType-Method goes?
I cannot find it anywhere and it does not appear to be a valid preFlush callback as you mentioned "before flush".
Also it looks like it's modifying the generator for the entire entity class. Who is setting it back to AUTO if there is another entity without a set id?

Comment: `changeIdGeneratorType` is probably a `generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)` function of _AbstractIdGenerator_ class.

Comment: `changeIdGeneratorType` is just the name of my own function. The important part is `if ($object->getId() !== null) {
         $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($object));
         $metadata->setIdGeneratorType($metadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
     }` There you check if an ID is already set, if this is `**true**` you tell your object to set the generator type of this instance to `NONE`, so it will apply your ID you have set before.

Comment: BTW sorry for this really late answer :-/

Comment: I added this code before saving my entity and it worked!, thank you